# For-loop and coordinate duplicates in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to detect duplicate coordinates in a series:

```
n <- 0
for(ii in 1:11){
  for(jj in 1:11){
w <- ii
x <- jj
y <- ii
z <- jj
coord1 <- c(w, x)
coord2 <- c(y, z)
list_coord <- list(coord1, coord2)
if(sum(duplicated(list_coord)) > 0) n <- n+1
print(n)
}}
```

This works.

However, as soon as I fix one of the coordinates, R returns only zeros although there should be at least one n = 1:

```
n <- 0
for(ii in 1:11){
  for(jj in 1:11){
    w <- ii
    x <- jj
    y <- 4
    z <- 7
    coord1 <- c(w, x)
    coord2 <- c(y, z)
    list_coord <- list(coord1, coord2)
    if(sum(duplicated(list_coord)) > 0) n <- n+1
    print(n)
  }}
```

Why? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duplicated` statement can be done on `rbind`ing the 'coord1', 'coord2'

```
n <- 0
for(ii in 1:11){
  for(jj in 1:11){
    w <- ii
    x <- jj
    y <- 4
    z <- 7
    coord1 <- c(w, x)
    coord2 <- c(y, z)
    new_coord <- rbind(coord1, coord2)   
    if(sum(duplicated(new_coord)) > 0) n <- n+1
    #or
    #if(anyDuplicated(new_coord) > 0) n <- n+1

    print(n)
  }}

n
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much akrun, it works. Could you please explain why it works with rbind and not with list??